# How to delete recently opened files using terminal

Tags: 12.04

In the Dash Home I used to see recently opened files and downloads, I want to delete those recent files so I do not see them again in the Dash Home.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that

Comment: No problem. Sometimes duplicates can be found by searching (which we very much encourage). But sometimes, especially if you [haven't yet found the final definition of your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), you'll end up posting a duplicate question in spite of your best efforts. (And sometimes, duplicates [can even contribute positively](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to the site by [acting as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) to the "master" question and making it easier to find than it was before.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete your history from dash search.

- Go to **System Settings**
- Open **Security  & Privacy**
- Under **Files and Applications** tab click on **Clear Usage Data**
- You can also turn off the "Record file and Application usage" to prevent system to  record your recent files and applications.

Comment: Thanks @G_P, I also was able to disable recording activities..